# I'm trying to import a new SSL certificate but somehow it's referring to the old one

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore, keytool

I have a host `abc.com` on which I have installed a SSL certificate, but due to some reason the host name was changed to `xyz.com` so I have created a new SSL certificate for this host but somehow it's still referring to the old certificate which was used for `abc.com`.

Following are the commands I've used to create Keystore and CSR file:

```
---KeyStore generation Command

keytool -genkey -alias xyz -keyalg RSA -keystore xyz.keystore -keysize 2048

--CSR file generation command

keytool -certreq -alias xyz -file xyz.csr -keystore xyz.keystore -sigalg SHA1withRSA
```

From CSR file I've generated the trusted certificate for site.
There are 3 certificates provided to me Root certificate, Issuer Certificate and Site Certiticate.

First I've imported Root certificate, then Issuer certificate and then site certificate using below commands into keystore:

```
-- Importing root certificate
keytool -keystore xyz.keystore -storetype JKS -storepass xyz123 -import -v -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias root -keypass xyz123 -file root.cer -keystore xyz.keystore -storetype JKS -storepass xyz123

-- Importing issuer certificate
keytool -keystore xyz.keystore -storetype JKS -storepass xyz123 -import -v -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias issuer -keypass xyz123 -file issuer.cer -keystore xyz.keystore -storetype JKS -storepass xyz123

-- Importing site certificate
keytool -keystore xyz.keystore -storetype JKS -storepass xyz123 -import -v -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias xyz -keypass xyz123 -file xyz.cer -keystore xyz.keystore -storetype JKS -storepass xyz123
```

Now to check if certificates are imported properly in the keystore I've used below command:

```
keytool -list -keystore xyz.keystore
```

I can see 4 entries in the keystore, 1 PrivateKeyEntry and 3 trustCertEntries.

Now I've used this keystore and its keyPass in the `Connector` tag of  server.xml file of tomcat. server.xml entry looks like below:

```
 <Connector port="8443" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" 
 maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100" 
 disableUploadTimeout="true" keystoreFile="xyz.keystore" keystorePass="xyz123"/>
```

I restarted the server and tried accessing the application but it's still referring to the old certificate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lots of searching I found this command,

```
keytool -list -keystore ~/.keystore -v
```

This will list out the certificates from the default keystore which is there at your home location. (`~/` means its your home location on linux)

And I could see the old certificate there. I removed the old certificate from there and then added the new keystore details to my `server.xml` file in tomcat and now its referring to the new certificate properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have specified `-trustcacerts` when importing the signed certificate. There should only be two trusted entries and one private key. You haven't disturbed the private key entry at all.

Comment: I tried removing `-trustcacerts` but still it's referring to old certificate.

Comment: I tried removing the reference from JVM arguments, server.xml but still it's referring to the old keystore somehow.